# Spacing between lhead and rhead content while wrapping

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am having troubles with wrapped text in the header.

At the moment it looks like this:
[image: two muppets]

And this is how I would like it to look like:
[image: two muppets]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{titling}  
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\geometry{a4paper, left=30mm,right=20mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm}

\setlength{\headheight}{12.7mm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\textbf{\thetitle}}
\rhead{\textit{\thepage}}

\title{This is a really long title which takes lot of space in header, so it is wrapped over to the next line.}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Basically I need some spacing between `lhead` and `rhead` content, no matter if `lhead` content will be wrapped into multiline.

Comment: Hi and welcome, the header is for orientation of the reader (where the duck am i?). Give it a shorter title for the header, you can do `\chapter[short title for toc and head]{long title which can, but shall not, confuse the reader by using many words}` for example.

Comment: by the way, very good example. Thanks for that.

Comment: Try `\lhead{\minipage[t]{.8\linewidth}\textbf{\thetitle}\endminipage}`. You can change the alignment by changing `[t]` to `[b]`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Unfortunately I am not allowed to shorten the title. But your last suggestion works like a charm. I would mark it as right answer, if it would not be a plain comment to my question. Anyway, thank you very much, you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I recommend to use option `includefoot` for the first page (if your page number is at the bottom).

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks for noticing. I am recreating the MS Word template of the department, where I am about to write my bachelor thesis. So the style of first page will be completely custom anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headers in a document are for orientation of the reader. The might want to know, in which part of a document he is (where the duck am i?).

So a header should not be very long, you can give shorter names for the table of contents and the header with `\chapter[short title for toc and head]{long title which can, but shall not, confuse the reader by using many many words}`. If you want to (have to) stick with a long header, you can use a minipage.

[image: kreideHeaderMinipage]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{titling}  
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\geometry{a4paper, left=30mm,right=20mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm}

\setlength{\headheight}{12.7mm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\minipage[b]{.8\linewidth}\textbf{\thetitle}\endminipage}
\rhead{\textit{\thepage}}

\title{This is a really long title which takes lot of space in
header, so it is wrapped over to the next line.}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

With the optional argument, you can change the alignment of the minipage in respect to the rest of the line (where the page number rests).